# Word for everything 'around' the central game screen or core of an application?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call this? Say you have a small webgame, is there one common word for things like the startscreen, registrationscreen, endscreen, options, etc.

So you have the 'Game Core' and 'XXX'. 
It's being used for writing an offer.

I thought about the word chrome that is sometimes used, but I have the feeling that refers more specfic to the UX elements on i.e. the game screen.

Comment: Isn't that usually called _main menu_?

Comment: *Chrome* is strictly a programming term and should not be used.

Comment: I agree, it sounds too nerdy. @alwayslearning, could be.. but that still sound really specific. I'm looking for something that could also include the registration process, invite a friend, social buttons etc

Comment: *Menu screens/pages* might be usable.

Comment: Sounds like that stuff "around" the core is *peripheral*.

Comment: When it comes to [tag:single-word-requests], “how it will be used” refers to the linguistic context (a sample sentence or paragraph etc), not the commercial context (*cf* “writing an offer”).

Comment: You mean: writing a **proposal**. offer is not used like that in English.

Answer (score 1):

You could call that stuff the **game user interface** or **game UI** or **game interface**. Doing a google search on any of the above returns a ton of results.

From [gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/game-ui-by-example-a-crash-course-in-the-good-and-the-bad--gamedev-3943):

> UI, or *User Interface*, refers to the methods (keyboard control, mouse control) and interfaces (inventory screen, map screen) through which a user interacts with your game. UX, or *User Experience*, refers to how intuitive and enjoyable those interactions are.

Comment: Going by OP's word usage, what you're describing is also part of the 'Game Core'. Technically speaking, _everything that is made visible by the game_ (or even just your computer) is UI. But in most cases, especially gaming, UI is intended to mean "things the player sees, but the characters in the game world cannot".

Answer (score 1):

Things that are not central are often called

> peripheral.

Where you're talking about operations, things that are not the main point of it and are there only to support these peripheral features might be called:

> support

or

> administrative.

Answer (score 0):

If we relate it to something similar is real life, you can consider the term ***dashboard***, which is most often used to describe the instrument panel of a car:

> **1** The panel facing the driver of a vehicle or the pilot of an aircraft, containing instruments and controls.
>   <sub>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/dashboard)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

You may want to call such things ***essentials***.

M-W:

> **[essential](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/essential)**
>   *noun*
>
> **1** :  something basic : *the essentials of astronomy*
>   **2** :  something necessary, indispensable, or unavoidable
>
> this will be just an introduction to the essentials of computer
>   programming

Comment: Has been downvoted by someone but I do like it actually

Answer (score -1):

Anything depicted "in front" of the game world can be called part of the **overlay**.

> **[overlay](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overlay)** *noun*
>
> 5.
> something laid over something else; covering.